# Decay of multidimensional arrays as function parameters

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I know that for example this:

```
void foo(int a[])// or a[x]
```

will be considered by the compiler like this:

```
void foo(int *a)
```

But I don't know, and I didn't found anywhere how are multidimensional arrays seen by the compiler

For example:

```
void foo(int a[3][4])
```

Will it be something like this?

```
void foo(int (*a)[4])
```

Or something like this?

```
void foo(int **a)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When an array decays, it converts into a pointer to the first element.  In the case of `int a[3][4]`, `a` is an array of `int[4]`, so a pointer to an element of `int [3][4]` has type `int (*)[4]`.

So this:

```
void foo(int a[3][4])
```

Is the same as:

```
void foo(int (*a)[4])
```

Answer (score 6):

The compiler cannot index a multi dimensional array passed to function correctly without knowing every dimension except the outermost.

So for a 1D array no length is needed:

```
void foo(int a[]);
```

and

```
void foo(int a[3]);
```

are equal although misleading, because C pays no attention to the length of an array: that is for the programmer to get right.

For a 2D array the inner dimension *does* have to be correct, or the compiler won't know how to index it. So

```
void foo(int a[][3]);
```

is good, but

```
void foo(int a[][]);
```

can't be coded, and

```
void foo(int a[42][3]);
```

is good but unnecessary, and not restrictive, since all the compiler needs is the information about **how** to index, and not **how much**.

Comment: "C pays no attention to the length of an array" - this only applies to the case of function parameters, not in general

Comment: @M.M Not sure that's the case. There's nothing to stop me from accessing some element past the end of any array in C. Just that a compiler is free to do some static analysis to try and guess if I get it right and warn me.

Comment: @Wilson it must pay attention to size of actual (non-function-parameter) array to e.g. make `sizeof` operator give the correct size.

Comment: @Wilson the compiler also considers the array length when initialising data is provided for the array definition. I wanted to keep the answer on topic not a full account of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Multidimensional arrays are often a source of problems, especially if you want to allow a dynamic size.

In the general case, I would suggest to use

```
void foo(int* a, int size1, int size2);
```

or

```
void foo(int* a, int numSizes, int* sizes);
```

Explicitly passing the size limits the very common segfaults you'd get because of the pointer decay and the lack of checking. Using array types is very brittle and not recommended in most cases.

You also might want to specify the indexing method, it's usually `a[size1*i+j]` but you might want something else.

Answer (score 1):

```
void foo(int a[3][4])
```

a is an array of length 3, consisting of 4-elemented int arrays.

So this is how it looks like:

```
+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
+---+---+---+---+
```

You can add rows, but you can't add columns, because accessing the element of an `k[3][4]` is done like `a[3][2] = a[3*4 + 2]`. This is how to find a box of the diagram above using the row and the column knowledge. The equation `a[b][c] = a[b * row_number + c]` doesn't hold when the matrix is non-square. Say,

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
+---+---+---+---+
```

Do you understand it?

Look at the first table above. It could be enumerated in a different way. How about:

```
+---+---+----+----+
| 0 | 1 | 2  | 3  |
+---+---+----+----+
| 4 | 5 | 6  | 7  |
+---+---+----+----+
| 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 |
+---+---+----+----+
```

actually (because it's an array, not a table)

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+----+
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+----+
```

See, in C, a 2D array is a one-dimensional array, just with different indices. So it could be written as:

```
void foo(int a[])
```

or

```
void foo(int *a)
```

What about

```
void foo(int **a)
```

It's an array of references to int arrays. This is not a 2D array. On the contrary, it may come in handy rarely. For instance, when you wanted to have a 2D array that the inner arrays (rows) have different lengths. Besides, it's how Java handles 2D arrays.